# Deleting everything from a text file after a certain point

Tags: c++, file-handling

This is my first post here. I am writing a program in C++ using file handling in which I have a given text file and I wish to delete everything in the file beyond a certain point at which my pointer is, after which the pointer should return to the same plae as before.

If anyone can help me I will be greatly obliged. I have not programmed in a long time.

Specifically in my program, I have,

> ...
>
> ofstream List;
>
> List.open("List.txt");
>
> ...
>
> List.seekp(i);

At this point I wish to delete everything in the file beyond the ith byte, and ensure that whatever further I write is from the ith place. How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4007734/951890

Comment: did you even googled it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically in text file processing you use two files, read from **original** and write to **temp**.  Then close **temp**, unlink **original** and rename **temp** to **original**.  One reason for doing it this way is that you don't lose everything if there is a crash part way through.  Second reason is that trying to do anything tricky may not work when you try to use it on a different filesystem.