# How to delete only the last line of a ASCII text file using C?

Tags: c, file-handling

I have a text file. How do I go about deleting only the last line in the file using C?

Thanks!
John.

Comment: What have you tried?  And/or what exactly is required for you to get full credit on your homework?

Comment: I've tried seeking to the EOF and then traversing back the to the next new line char. And LOL @ your insinuation that this is HW. Thanks for your concern, but I'm not a student. I have to delete the last record of a text file as an export operation in Excel is adding a new line char to the end.

Answer (score 6):

Plain ANSI C doesn't provide any standard way to decrease the size of a file - the only way to do this in standard C is to copy the entire file contents to a new file, except for the part you want to omit.

Alternatively, you can use OS-specific functions to truncate the file in-place.  For example, POSIX provides the `ftruncate()` function, which shortens a file to a given length.  You would search for the beginning of the last line, then truncate the file immediately before this (using `lseek()` to obtain the position).

---

The easiest alternative of all, if you have GNU `head`, is just to use that:

```
head -n -1 < file.original > file.new
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct with the approach. Sacn for newlines, remember the last one and then use `truncate` or `ftruncate`. see also [How to truncate a file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873454/how-to-truncate-a-file-in-c) .

hth

Mario