# How to truncate a file from the end? (cross platform)

Tags: c++, file, io, truncate

I am trying to find a cross-platform method to delete `X` bytes from the end of a file.

Currently I have found:

- Platform specific solutions (such as truncate for posix) : This is what I don't want, because I want the C++ program to run on multiple platforms.
- Read in the whole file, and write out the file again minus the bytes I want to delete: I would like to avoid this as much as I can since I want the program to be as efficient and fast as possible

Any ideas?

If there is a "go to end of file stream" method/function, could I then rewind X bytes and cut the remainder of the file off or something similar?

Comment: You can write a cross-platform wrapper for the platform-specific methods.

Comment: duplicate eof http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873454/how-to-truncate-a-file-in-c

Comment: "I want the C++ program to run on multiple platforms" Could you tell us which platforms you want to run on?

Comment: Well frankly, I'm using just unix, but this is an assignment so ideally, any platform that supports C++.

Comment: @user1255592: That's potentially infinite. I could implement a C++ interpreter in my chest hair... should you support that?

Comment: By any platform I mean code that doesn't require platform specific functions.

Comment: @user1255592: Would you like fries with that?

Comment: May be try use boost::filesystem. It contains function resize_file

Comment: @Lightness As long as it's braided it should be supported.

Comment: @mikithskegg: Boost is not available on "any platform that supports C++"

Comment: (a) I'm not "worked up" (b) Don't tell me to chill (c) I'm trying to train you to think in precise terms, which will make you a better programmer. There is no "mocking" going on. Jumping to that conclusion is just a waste of your time and mine, not to mention ungrateful.

Answer (score 4):

How do you think cross platform functions work? Just make your own function like this:

```
int truncate(int fd, long size)
{
#ifdef _WIN32 || _WIN64 
    return _chsize(fd, size);
#else
  #ifdef POSIX
    return ftruncate(fd, size);
  #else
    // code for other OSes
  #endif
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing in the Standard library. They support streams- but streams don't have ends, files happen to have ends- at the current time.

All you can do is write a cross-platform wrapper on the function.

Comment: Ok... a slightly different but related question; For a given OS, say windows. How exactly does the OS know when its reached the end of a file? Is there an EOF byte or something similar? If so, what is the implementation of this in other platforms? (e.g. linux)

Comment: I asked this because I was wondering if it was possible to simply put that byte when I want to truncate it off.

Answer (score 0):

The [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem) library (version 1.44 and above) provides a [resize_file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#resize_file) function.