# Change file size with Android NDK

Tags: c++, file, android-ndk

How can I change the size of a file with the Android NDK in C++?

Usually I would use _chsize_s but it doesn't seem to be supported in the NDK. Is there a way to do this that works with the Android NDK?

Comment: dupplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873454/how-to-truncate-a-file-in-c

Comment: not a duplicate because I can't use ftruncate() or _chsize() in the Android NDK

Comment: bionic has ftruncate() https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/include/unistd.h#L150