# Resizing a file in C++

Tags: c++, file, resize

I am surprised to say that I have not found a reasonable solution on how to resize a file using C++ standard libraries. It seems completely stupid and wasteful to have to read in the data from the original file, and then write it into a different file. I simply want a resize method that will chop off the data that goes beyond that size... Is there anything that does this?

EDIT: If I do have to use the method I explained above, how large should my buffer be that I'm using to read/write? I obviously can't read the whole file in at once, because I am working with rather large files here.

Comment: This would cause file fragmentation which you would have to clean up but you could just over-write the end of the files with EOF characters?

Comment: What's the bigger picture here? "Resize" has many meanings!

Comment: Is invoking a OS API allowed in your project? Linux has a system call `truncate` setting files to specified length. I think Windows will provide comparative API. BTW, what's your platform?

Comment: `truncate()` in `<unistd.h>` is part of the POSIX C libraries, would that work?

Comment: @Summer_More_More_Tea Invoking an OS API is okay, but this is a cross platform project. As long as I have a solution for every platform, I can just use pre-processors.

Comment: @hetelek as @trutheality pointed out, `truncate` is a POSIX API. So cross-platform is not that much a problem, only if your OS API compatible with POSIX standard. Good luck!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

File resize without loading full image is pretty complex task even for higher level languages, it’s mostly a feature of image processing SDKs like [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

If there are no specific requirements for resize quality or supported formats I guess Mark’s answer will be the easiest way. Otherwise you need to include graphics format libraries and implement some resize algorithm manually (or use some lib too).

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. I think I will go with the reading/writing method.

Comment: Where did you get images/pictures from? The OP makes zero mention.

Comment: It's here by mistake. Unfortunately, I can't delete the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the functions provided by [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/libs/filesystem/), specifically its [resize_file()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#resize_file) function.

Please note that Boost.Filesystem is (planned to be) included in future iterations of the language standard. See [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1975.html). That's good news if you don't want to use Boost in your project.

Also, as what @BenjaminLindley had mentioned, the `<filesytem>` header is already available in Visual Studio 2012 ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx); search for "filesystem").

Comment: Thanks for this, but unfortunately my project does not rely on Boost and I would like to keep it this way.

Comment: @hetelek Why not? You may not use everything it offers, but you'll sure find some parts of it that may save much of your development time.

Comment: @MarkGarcia I have nothing against Boost, but I have a large project that doesn't rely on boost anywhere else, and I will not use it just for this without going back and changing them all. Also, I simply enjoy the fact that it only relies on standard libraries.

Comment: @hetelek Then simply reimplement boost filesystem in your project.  It is open source, the code is right there.  Start typing...

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 11, the `<filesystem>` header is already there. I'm sure other major vendors will shortly follow suit.

Answer (score 6):

C++17 has [std::filesystem::resize_file()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/resize_file)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there is no cross-platform method for resizing the file, because the Standard does not describe this functionality.
But, as it is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873454/how-to-truncate-a-file-in-c), there are platform APIs for this purpose: see _chsize() function for Windows, truncate() and ftruncate() function for POSIX systems.