# File truncate and padding in C

Tags: c, linux, file-io

How can I truncate a file with the given size and if the filesize is smaller then the given size how can I enlarge the existing file size with 0 padding.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Not a real dupes, as this question is about resizing a file in general, not only about shrinking.

Answer (score 1):

To skrink use `truncate()` or `ftruncate()`, to enlarge use `lseek()`/`fseek()` followed by `write()`/`fwrite()`ing one byte.

Comment: Is there any other way to enlarge the size.

Comment: @user503403: Without (seeking and) writing? No.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you with truncation:

[How to truncate a file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873454/how-to-truncate-a-file-in-c)

And I do not think you can enlarge a file without some kind of padding (it depends on how you view "padding").

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved in this [How to truncate a file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873454/how-to-truncate-a-file-in-c)
Basically, you can use these two functions:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int ftruncate(int fildes, off_t length);
int truncate(const char *path, off_t length);
```