# Working with files in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, file, file-io

Let's say I write some information in a file, and it writes with `n` cycles, for example as follows:

```
a,a,a,a,
b,b,b,b,
c,c,c,c,
a,a,a,a,
b,b,b,b,
c,c,c,c,
.......
a,a,a,a,
b,b,b,b,
c,c,c,c,
```

Now I want to open the file check the first line, find where it repeats and delete everything after that. For my example case let's say I want to wind where `a,a,a,a,` meets again, and to delete it, and everything after that, getting the follows instead:

```
a,a,a,a,
b,b,b,b,
c,c,c,c,
```

Q: How can I do that?

Comment: [What do you have so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: @Angew I don't have any idea how to do it directly in the file.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873454/how-to-truncate-a-file-in-c).

Comment: Start by skimming through `QFile` docs, and reading everything relevant you spot. Then refine the question to be a bit more specific...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QTextStream to stream your file (so, do not care about RAM).
Then use readLine() function to read one line at a time to QString, and compare with new line.
Here some code sample:

```
int lineCounter = 0; //count for line
QFile f(filePath);
if (!f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    return false;
QTextStream stream(&f);
QString line;
// read the first line
line = stream.readLine();
lineCounter++;
QString hash = QString(QCryptographicHash::hash(line.toAscii(), QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex());
do
{
    line = stream.readLine();
    if (QString(QCryptographicHash::hash(line.toAscii(), QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex()).compare(hash) == 0)
    {
        // Save data from 1st line to "lineCounter" to new file, or do your own works;
        // and then break;
    }
    lineCounter++;
} while (!line.isNull());
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove duplicate lines in a file. If you follow the next steps you will get what you want.

- Create a vector that will store the hashes of unique lines ( `QVector<QString>`) Notice that using `QMap` would be faster.
- Create an ouput file
- For every line in the file calculate it's hash. Use [`QCryptographicHash`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qcryptographichash.html) or [`qHash`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qhash.html#qHash-22) (in this case you should have a vector of `uints`.

  - If the calculated hash is contained in the vector skip this line
  - Otherwise add the hash to the vector and print the line to the output file.
- At the end the output file should contain only unique instances of the input file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. That does not actually fit me, as the number of cycles can be very big, and I do not want to keep so much information in RAM. I want to do everything directly in the file.

Comment: @Mike create a temp file. It's not possible to insert or delete in a middle of a file. Not sure if you want this, but sounds like it.