# What are the arguments to ftruncate()?

Tags: c, file, posix

I am trying to use the function `ftruncate()` to truncate a file.

I know from looking online that it goes like this:

```
int ftruncate(int fildes, off_t length);
```

But I don't know what to supply for the arguments `int fd` and `off_t length`.

Comment: Show what you have attempted and Ask a question with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @VishaalShankar: he seems to be asking how the function is used, rather than having a run-time problem.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument is the file descriptor. This is the handle to the file that you get from functions like [`open(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/open) or [`creat(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/creat). The second argument is the size you want to truncate the file to. Use `0` if you want to truncate it completely. Finally, the returned value is `0` if the operation was successful and `-1` otherwise (and [`errno(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/errno) is set accordingly). For more information, see [`ftruncate(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ftruncate).

However, it might be the case that you are confused because you are trying to use a POSIX function instead of C or C++ standard ones. If so, check out [How to truncate a file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873454/how-to-truncate-a-file-in-c) and similar questions for solutions that rely only on the C or C++ standards.