# Can we reduce size of existing file?

Tags: c++, c, file-io, fstream, file-handling

I want to know whether size of text or binary file can be reduced without creating temporary file. So that we can delete the data present at very end of file.

If yes then how. If no then why.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to *truncate* a file to a given size.

Comment: LOL How was this question "unclear"?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873454

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can reduce file size using `truncate()` or `ftruncate()` functions that are available on POSIX systems.

For Windows, use `SetFilePointer` to set the current position to desired file size, then call `SetEndOfFile` to actually truncate it.

Comment: You could also mention the new (standard) *filesystem* option for `C++17`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/resize_file

Comment: Thanks a lot, it saved too many calls to file io

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [resize_file()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/resize_file) function from the `<filesystem>` addition to the Standard Library in `C++17`:

```
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

// ...

fs::resize_file(p, 1024); // resize to 1024 bytes
```

Comment: Will use it future. Currently I'm using older standard.