# Clearing file contents only using FILE *

Tags: c, file, evc4

I need to clear the content of a file, but the path of that file is not reachable, unless i do large modifications. I only have the stream pointer (`FILE *`). I could do reopen() but, it is not available on EVC4.

Is there another way to clear a file's contents only using a `FILE *`?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that i'm coding on/for Windows, even though EVC4 is a Windows only IDE.

Comment: The second answer works on Windows.

Comment: It doesn't seem to. This function expects an integer and not a FILE pointer, so unless it is possible to cast a FILE * to an integer, it won't work.

Comment: That would be the `fileno` part, which gets the file descriptor corresponding to a `FILE *`.

Comment: int changesize(FILE *fp, __int64 size)
{
    int filedes = _fileno(fp);
    return _chsize_s(filedes, size);
}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584639/truncate-file